# How can i add delivery fees on Stripe payment?

Tags: javascript, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe and trying to add delivery fees but I can't.

How to achieve this?

```js
let line_items = [];
  for (let productId of uniqIds) {
    const quantity = productsIds.filter(id => id === productId).length;
    const product = products.find(p => p._id.toString() === productId);
    line_items.push({
      quantity,
      price_data: {
        currency: 'EUR',
        product_data: {name:product.name},
        unit_amount: product.price * 100,
      },
    });

 const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: line_items,
    mode: 'payment',
    customer_email: email,
    success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?success=true`,
    cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?canceled=true`,
    metadata: {orderId:order._id.toString()},
  });
```

I tried to add "product.price*100+5" + (the amount of the delivery costs)
But it doesn't work because it's the price per unitI tried to add "product.price*100+5" + (the amount of the delivery costs)
But it doesn't work because it's the price per unit

Comment: What is the Stripe product you are using?  I see you are building an array called `line_items` but it isn't clear what that is going to be added to.

Comment: I followed the doc : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment I try to accept a payment, I succeeded but I don't know how to add delivery costs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so you are using Checkout to collect the payment from your customer.  Stripe currently allows you to set a `fixed_amount` charge for shipping when creating the Checkout Session.

You can do this by [creating a Shipping Rate](https://stripe.com/docs/api/shipping_rates/create) and passing it in when [creating the Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-shipping_options-shipping_rate).  Or you can create the Shipping Rate within the Checkout Session create call by specifying [shipping_rate_data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-shipping_options-shipping_rate_data).

This allows you to provide a flat shipping cost in addition to the cost of the `line_items` you created in your `for` loop.